# Why Android Studio emulator shows black screen?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

Hi, when I press **"Run"** button, that is what compiler do. Just **black screen**. What is wrong? What option should I check?

Comment: Did you try clicking on the power button on  emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on the power. Click On the power icon Or use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hi @AgentP, I tried to turn on the device, but no reaction. I tried to launch AVD from "AVD Manager" (every time) and after this I push run. Then it works.